# How can i distinguish which UIAlertView's button was clicked from multiple alertview

Tags: iphone

In my appln I m using multiple UIAlertView and to determine which between was clicked in alertview i use the method

```
- (void) alertView:(UIAlertView *)alert clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
```

}

but i need only for the one alertview but it was responding for all alertviews. how to restrict to only to one alertview or to alertview to which i need determine the button action

Answer (score 3):

Common practice is to use a unique number for the [tag](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW25) property of each `UIAlertView`, and then check the tag in your delegate callbacks. An easy way to do this is with an enum:

```
 enum {
     kServiceErrorAlert = 1,
     kFailedToSaveAlert = 2
 };

 ...

 alertView.tag = kServiceErrorAlert;
 [alertView show];
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can afford to run on 4.x only, you can use blocks and forget about delegates and tags:

```
LambdaAlert *alert = [[LambdaAlert alloc]
    initWithTitle:@"Test Alert"
    message:@"See if the thing works."];
[alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Foo" block:^{ NSLog(@"Foo"); }];
[alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Bar" block:^{ NSLog(@"Bar"); }];
[alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel" block:NULL];
[alert show];
[alert release];
```

See [LambdaAlert on GitHub](https://github.com/zoul/Lambda-Alert).

Comment: in iPhone time iOS 4.x has been out for ages :) great answer